# Error when copying and pasting file into content editable div

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari

I have a content editable element and I have paste of text and bitmap data working but when someone pastes an actual file into the element the icon is loaded and not the image.

The correct image name, type and size is reported but when loaded it's only the icon in Firefox and in Safari it only works on some images. 
 [image]

This happens in Firefox and Safari. I've created a generic jsfiddle and example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59518sfv/32/) and example below.

I'm using a variety of methods to get clipboard data since some browsers work slightly differently (code below).

In some cases, I was able to get a FileError code 4, where code 4, a  FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR that might also be the same error that shows in the console on some images.

> Failed to load resource: The operation could not be completed.
>   WebKitBlobResource error 4.

Steps to reproduce:
1. copy anyimage.png from Finder
2. right click on content editable div and select paste (or use Command + v)

What is shown is the image icon.

```js
  // Handle pasting into content editable element
  // 
  // three methods
  // 1. get image data from the clipboard items
  // 2. get image data from clipboard files
  // 3. wait and get image data from content editable div

  // handling these cases test
  // 1. get text pasted from clipboard
  // 2. get image pasted from clipboard
  // 3. get text from content editable element
  // 4. get image from content editable element
  // 5. get dropped file reference from Finder
  // 6. get pasted file reference from Finder
  // 
  // Item 6, get pasted file reference doesn't work in Firefox or Safari

processPaste = function(pasteData) {
  console.log("ProcessPaste called");
  var application = document.getElementById("application");
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var output = JSON.stringify(pasteData);
  console.log(pasteData);
  image.src = pasteData.dataURI;
  //image.style.width = "100px";
  //image.style.height = "100px";
  //document.body.appendChild(image);
  //console.log(pasteData);
  //console.log(output);
  application.innerHTML = output.split(",").join(",\n\t");
}

addPasteListeners = function (id, debug) {
  var useCapture = true;
  var eventName = "paste";
  var element;

  if (id=="body") {
    element = document.body;
  }
  else if (id=="window") {
    element = window;
  }
  else {
    element = document.getElementById(id);
  }

  if (debug) {
    console.log("Adding listener for: " + eventName + " to " + element);
  }

  if (element==null) {
    if (debug) console.log("Element was not found: " + id);
    return true;
  }

  if (application==null) {
    if (debug) console.log("application was not found: " + objectId);
    return true;
  }


  var pasteFunction = function(event) {
    var isDefaultPrevented = false;
    var items = [];
    var numberOfItems = 0;
    var numberOfFiles = 0;
    var numberOfNodes = 0;
    var files;
    var fileObject;
    var reader;
    var clipboardData;
    var itemType;
    var itemKind;
    var blob;
    var types;
    var type;
    var quality = 1;
    var clipboardItems = [];
    var clipboardFiles = [];
    var useFileArray = false;
    var childNodes;
    var loadedFile;
    const PLAIN_TEXT = "text/plain";
    const IMAGE_PNG = "image/png";
    const INVALID = "invalid";


    if (debug) console.log("Paste event handler");

    clipboardData = event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
    types = clipboardData.types;

    if (clipboardData.items && clipboardData.items.length) {
      items = clipboardData.items; // DataTransferItem in DataTransferItemList
      for(var k=0;k<items.length;k++) {
        clipboardItems.push({kind:items[k].kind, type:items[k].type});
      };
      numberOfItems = items.length;
    }

    // if files available use them instead of clipboard
    if (clipboardData.files && clipboardData.files.length) {
      items = clipboardData.files; // File in FileList
      for(var m=0;m<items.length;m++) {
        clipboardFiles.push({name:items[m].name,type:items[m].type,size:items[m].size}); // file
      };
      numberOfFiles = items.length;
    }

    if (numberOfItems!=0 && numberOfFiles!=0 && useFileArray) {
      items = clipboardData.items;
    }

    files = {};
    fileObject = {};
    fileObject.type = INVALID;

    if (debug) console.log("Item count:" + items.length);
    if (debug) console.log(event);

    // dispatch before paste event
    fileObject.types = types;
    fileObject.numberOfItems = numberOfItems;
    fileObject.numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles;
    fileObject.clipboardItems = clipboardItems;
    fileObject.clipboardFiles = clipboardFiles;
    fileObject.numberOfNodes = 0;    
    fileObject.eventType = "paste";
    //debugger;

    // if no items in the clipboard loop through the container elements
    if (numberOfItems==0) {
      childNodes = element.childNodes;
      numberOfNodes = childNodes ? childNodes.length : 0;

      // we call this after a frame 
      getImageDataURI = function() {
        if (debug) console.log("GetImageDataURI");
        childNodes = element.childNodes;
        numberOfNodes = childNodes ? childNodes.length : 0;

        fileObject.numberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;

        for (var j = 0; j < numberOfNodes; j++) {
          var child = childNodes[j];
          var nodeType = child && "nodeType" in child ? child.nodeType : null;
          var tag = child && "tagName" in child && child.tagName ? child.tagName.toLowerCase() : "";
          var nodeName = child && "nodeName" in child && child.nodeName ? child.nodeName.toLowerCase() : "";

          fileObject.index = j;

          // type 3 is text node, 1 is html element
          if (debug) console.log("Text node:" + nodeName);

          // pasted file
          if (nodeName=="attachment" && child.file) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.file = child.file;

            // file load handler
            reader.addEventListener("loadend", function (e) {
              var currentReader = e.target;

              loadedFile = currentReader.file; // our reference

              fileObject.origin = "fileFromContentEditable";
              fileObject.dataURI = currentReader.result;
              fileObject.name = loadedFile.name;
              fileObject.type = loadedFile.type;
              fileObject.kind = "kind" in loadedFile ? loadedFile.kind : null;


              if (debug) console.log("File loaded:" + fileObject.type);
              if (debug) console.log(loadedFile);
              if (debug) console.log(currentReader);

              processPaste(fileObject);
            });

            // file error handler
            // FileError.code is 4; FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR = 4
            reader.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
              var currentReader = e.target;

              loadedFile = currentReader.file; // our reference

              fileObject.name = loadedFile.name;
              fileObject.error = e;
              if (debug) console.log("File loaded error:" + loadedFile.type);
              if (debug) console.log(loadedFile);
              if (debug) console.log(currentReader);

              processPaste(fileObject);
            });

            if (debug) console.log("Reading file as data URL");
            reader.readAsDataURL(reader.file);

          }

          else if (nodeName=="#text" || nodeType==3) {
            if (debug) console.log("Text data");
            type = PLAIN_TEXT;
            fileObject.value = child.nodeValue;
            fileObject.name = "";
            fileObject.type = type;
            fileObject.origin = "nodeValue";

            //fileObject.size = canvas.toBlob(callback); // convert to blob to get size

            processPaste(fileObject);
          }
          else if (tag === "img") {
            // fetching the blob via the URL - is returning TIFF on Safari
            var fetchFromURL = false;
            var image = child;
            type = IMAGE_PNG;

            // default is to draw to canvas. alternative is fetch from url
            if (!fetchFromURL) {

              var drawImage = function() {
                if (debug) console.log("Drawing image");
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
                canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                fileObject.dataURI = canvas.toDataURL(IMAGE_PNG, quality);
                fileObject.name = "";
                fileObject.type = type;
                fileObject.origin = "canvas";
                fileObject.width = image.naturalWidth;
                fileObject.height = image.naturalHeight;

                //fileObject.size = canvas.toBlob(callback); // convert to blob to get size
                if (debug) console.log("Image captured:" + type);

                processPaste(fileObject);
              }

              if (image.naturalWidth) {
                drawImage();
              } 
              else {
                image.onload = drawImage;
              }
            }
            else {
              var url = child.src;

              // read blob url into data uri
              if (url && url.indexOf("blob")===0) {
                if (debug) console.log("Parsing blob URL into DataURI");
                fileObject.origin = "DataURIFromBlobURI";

                var getDataURIFromBlobURI = function(url) {
                  return fetch(url).then(function(response) {
                    return response.blob();
                  }).then(function (blob) {
                    type = blob.type;
                    size = blob.size;
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                      const reader = new FileReader();
                      reader.onerror = reject;
                      reader.onloadend = function(progressEvent) {
                        return resolve(reader.result);
                      }
                      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                    }
                                      )}
                         )}

                getDataURIFromBlobURI(url).then(function(dataURI) {
                  if (debug) console.log("DataURI:" + dataURI);
                  fileObject.dataURI = dataURI;
                  fileObject.type = type;
                  fileObject.size = size;
                  processPaste(fileObject);
                }, function(err) {
                  if (debug) console.log("Read as URL error");
                  fileObject.name = null;
                  fileObject.dataURI = null;

                  processPaste(fileObject);
                })
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      window.key = setTimeout(getImageDataURI, 1);
      return;
    }

    //debugger;

    // loop through items in the clipboard - not supported in safari osx atm
    // item in items can be DataTransferItem or File
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
      if (items[i]==null) continue; // clipboard items may be emptied
      // when item is DataTransferItem the value is "string" or "file". when item is File value is null
      itemKind = items[i].kind;
      itemType = Object.prototype.toString.call(items[i]).slice(8, -1);
      type = items[i].type; // mime type
      if (debug) console.log("Item["+i+"]: " + type);

      // local references seem to be overwritten when in a loop for some reason
      files[i] = items[i];

      if (debug) console.log(items[i]);

      // if DataTransferItem and is string
      if (itemKind=="string" && "getAsString" in items[i]) {
        items[i].getAsString(function(value) {
          fileObject.origin = "stringFromClipboard";

          fileObject.value = value;
          //fileObject.name = name;
          fileObject.type = type;
          fileObject.kind = itemKind;

          if (debug) console.log(itemKind + " from clipboard:" + value.slice(0, 100)+"...");

          processPaste(fileObject);
        });

        continue;
      }
      // if not string - DataTransferItem or File 
      else if (itemKind=="file" || itemType=="File") {
        if (debug) console.log("Pasted item is not string");

        if ("getAsFile" in items[i]) {
          blob = items[i].getAsFile();
        }
        else if ("webkitGetAsEntry" in items[i]) {
          blob = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        }
        else if ("getData" in items[i]) {
          blob = items[i].getData();
          // is DataTransferItem
        }
        else if (items[i] instanceof File) {
          blob = items[i];
        }

        if (debug) console.log(blob);
      }

      if (blob==null) {
        fileObject.error = "content is null";
        fileObject.type = type;
        fileObject.kind = itemKind;
        processPaste(fileObject);
        continue;
      }

      reader = new FileReader();
      reader.file = files[i]; // keep a reference when out of loop

      // file load handler
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", function (e) {
        var currentReader = e.target;

        loadedFile = currentReader.file; // our reference

        if (clipboardFiles.length) {
          fileObject.origin = "fileFromClipboard";
        }
        else {
          fileObject.origin = "itemFromClipboard";
        }
        fileObject.dataURI = currentReader.result;
        fileObject.name = loadedFile.name;
        fileObject.type = loadedFile.type;
        fileObject.kind = "kind" in loadedFile ? loadedFile.kind : null;


        if (debug) console.log("File loaded:" + fileObject.type);
        if (debug) console.log(loadedFile);
        if (debug) console.log(currentReader);
        
        processPaste(fileObject);
      });

      // file error handler
      reader.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
        var currentReader = e.target;

        loadedFile = currentReader.file; // our reference

        fileObject.name = loadedFile.name;
        fileObject.error = e;
        if (debug) console.log("File loaded error:" + loadedFile.type);
        if (debug) console.log(loadedFile);
        if (debug) console.log(currentReader);

        processPaste(fileObject);
      });

      // if blob found read as data URI
      // typically image/png but could also be text/rtf, text/plain, text/html
      if (blob) {
        if (debug) console.log("Reading blob as data URL");
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      }
    }

    if (debug) console.log("End of paste event handler");
  }

  element.addEventListener(eventName, pasteFunction, useCapture);


  if (debug) console.log("End of add paste listener");
  return true;
}

addPasteListeners("editor", true);
```

```css
#image {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
#editor {
  background-color:rgb(220,220,220);
  height:120px;
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#container {
  height:120px;
  width:100%;
}
#application {
  background-color:rgb(220,220,250);
  height:120px;
  width:99%;
  display:block;
}
[contenteditable]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div>Click on area below and then paste</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <img id="image">
</div>
<textarea id="application" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59518sfv/32/).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: My tests show that it is not supported on Safari at the time I wrote the question (or limited support). It then came down to some images working and others not working (on both or Firefox). I might have a similar question with more of these details if you check my questions (check the link). I found another user on github confirm lack of support on Safari in their online RichTextEditor.

Comment: I think what I eventually did was put a try catch around the call if I don't have it already, and alerted the user to use another method when things failed. I'll have to check later. I also ran into some issues with transparency in Firefox but it is or may be an unrelated issue (copy to clipboard). I don't remember.